# Find files in a loop and delete them

Tags: ansible

I would like to delete file in some sub directory which contains certain format. However, I am getting the error

> 'dict object' has no attribute 'files'.

Below is my code. The file pattern would be `file_name.file_extension.processID.YYYY-MM-DD@HH:MM:SS~`

My variables

```
fileToFindInAllSubDirecotry
  - "home/usr/file1"
  - "home/usr/file2"
  - "home/usr/file3/file4"
  - "home/usr/file5"
```

My playbook role

```
- name: Find file
  find:
    paths: "{{ item }}"
    use_regex: yes
    patterns:
      - '.*\.\d+\.\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}@\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}~$'
    age: 1d
    recurse: yes
  register: fileToDelete
  loop: "{{ fileToFindInAllSubDirecotry }}"
  
- name: Delete file
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ fileToDelete.files }}"
```

This is the sample file and directory

```
home
   |-------usr
             |-------file1
                         |-------configFile.xml
             |-------file2
                         |-------propertiesFile.txt.2012.2020-07-13@23:08:10~
             |-------file3
                         |-------file4
                                     |-------content.yml.2012.2020-04-04@23:08:10~                       
             |-------file5
                         |-------configFile.xml.2012.2020-03-05@13:08:10~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are populating the `find` with a loop, so you end up with a result that would be a dictionary having a list or `results`.

Something like:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                ...
                "files": [ ... ],
                ...
                "item": "/home/usr/file1",
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
                "files": [ ... ],
                ...
                "item": "/home/usr/file2",
                ...
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

There is two ways to fix this:

1. The nicest one, because, as pointed by the documentation, the [`paths`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#parameter-paths) parameter of the module find can accept lists of paths, just pass it your whole `fileToFindInAllSubDirecotry` variables instead of using a loop, this way your deletion works as is:

   ```yaml
   - name: Find file
     find:
       paths: "{{ fileToFindInAllSubDirecotry }}"
       use_regex: yes
       patterns:
         - '.*\.\d+\.\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}@\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}~$'
       age: 1d
       recurse: yes
     register: fileToDelete

   - name: Delete file
     file:
       path: "{{ item.path }}"
       state: absent
     loop: "{{ fileToDelete.files }}"
   ```
2. Use [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) to fetch the `result[*].files` then [`flatten`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#list-filters) the resulting list of list

   ```yaml
   - name: Find file
     find:
       paths: "{{ item }}"
       use_regex: yes
       patterns:
         - '.*\.\d+\.\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}@\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}~$'
       age: 1d
       recurse: yes
     register: fileToDelete
     loop: "{{ fileToFindInAllSubDirecotry }}"

   - name: Delete file
     file:
       path: "{{ item.path }}"
       state: absent
     loop: "{{ fileToDelete | json_query('results[*].files') | flatten }}"
   ```